# Getting Updated HTML Source

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsoup

I'm trying to get the `HTML` source code of a website that doesn't have all content available right off the bat. The reloading of HTML is done via `JavaScript`. When I try to connect to the `URL` and get the `HTML` it will not contain everything.

This is my code so far:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;

public class AudioLibrary
{
    public static void main(String[] arguments) throws IOException
    {
        String htmlSource = Jsoup
                .connect("https://www.youtube.com/audiolibrary/music").get()
                .html();
        System.out.println(htmlSource);
    }
}
```

How do I make sure that [`JavaScript`](https://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/www-audiolibrary-vfl1k5_oE/www-audiolibrary.js) finishes its job before retrieving the HTML source? In my case it obviously is the list of free downloadable music from the [YouTube Audio Library](https://www.youtube.com/audiolibrary/music).

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript runs in the browser, so all you will get is the basic page, probably with the JavaScript code, but not the final, modified HTML page, created by the JavaScript since you never execute the JavaScript.

You are downloading basically a text file (HTML). That's it. If you were a browser, you would now run the JavaScript in the page which would then modify this HTML. But since you don't run the JavaScript, nothing gets modified and you are stuck with the basic page.